# Are all DNN models supervised learning (or reinforcement learning)?

Tags: deep-learning

Are there any type of unsupervised learning models in DNN?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning#Neural_networks

Answer (score 1):

There are many types of unsupervised learning models in deep neural networks. One common type is an [autoencoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder), which learns a compressed representation of the data.